# How to access global variables by a oops in perl

Tags: perl, oop

I have written code but I don't know how to access global variable directly in other module

**Test1 file**

```
package Test1;

use strict;

sub new(@) {
    my $class = shift; 
    (bless {}, $class)->init(ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH' ? @_ : {@_}) 
}

sub init(@) { 
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    $self->{$_} = $args->{$_} foreach (keys %{$args});
    $self;
}

sub downloadable {
    my ($self) = @_;
    require Downloadable;
    $self->{downloadable} ||= Downloadable->new();
    return $self->{downloadable};
}

sub temp {
    my ($self)=@_;

    print $self->downloadable()->gaurav; 
    #gaurav is global variable of Downloadable file 
}

my $obj=Test1->new();

$obj->temp();
```

**Downloadable file**

```
package Downloadable;

sub new(@) {
    my $class = shift; 
    (bless {}, $class)->init(ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH' ? @_ : {@_}); 
}

#
sub init(@) {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    $self->{$_} = $args->{$_} foreach (keys %{$args});
    $self;
}

our $gaurav="he is gud boy";
```

Comment: FYI - if you're using prototypes in object-oriented perl, you're doing it wrong.  Remove all the `(@)`s from your `sub` lines, they're not doing anything, which means they aren't doing what you think they're doing, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to be able to access the value in `$guarav` via methods like `print $self->downloadable()->gaurav`, then I suggest you take advantage of [`use constant`](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html):

```
package Downloadable;

use constant gaurav => "he is gud boy";
```

This works because `constant` works by creating a subroutine with the key name.  That is why a bareword `gaurav` will return the value.  And because this is inside a class, it can be thought of and treated like a class method.  You could just've easily have done `sub gaurav { "he is gud boy" }`, but that wouldn't look nearly as clever, nor semantically communicate your intent.

Comment: @Suor brief explanation provided.